# Blockchain transaction goes missing when searched from a few sites

Tags: transactions, unconfirmed-transactions

So I have an unconfirmed transaction since almost a week now.
The transaction ID is fd82fb9711afc48623fa13fa3963121f88160afe56fc968feaf02e5f73e7b764

This is due to the fact that exchange cex.io to save money bunch a huge number of requests in a single transaction which effectively brought down the satoshi/byte.

Today when I searched for the transaction in a few blockchain sites it says transaction Not found. Sites like blockchain.info show the transaction but multiple sites like live.blockcypher.com, blockchair.com, blockexplorer.com etc all show transaction missing.

What does this mean? Is it that my transaction will be dropped finally? I prefer it being dropped as this will never get confirmed. What is the sure way of checking if a transaction is dropped?

Answer (score 1):

The transaction still shows on blockchain.info:
https://blockchain.info/tx/fd82fb9711afc48623fa13fa3963121f88160afe56fc968feaf02e5f73e7b764

You can never be sure a transaction is completely dropped because every node maintains its own mempool with potentially different rules for dropping transactions. And you never know, it may be confirmed any time despite the fee. cex.io who sent it is the only ones (other than miners) who can do anything about it anyway, so perhaps contact them, but likely you will just have to wait.

See also: [Why is my transaction not getting confirmed and what can I do about it?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9046/why-is-my-transaction-not-getting-confirmed-and-what-can-i-do-about-it)

Comment: Yes I have contacted them and trying everything I can to get it confirmed, but right now I was wondering why some sites which were showing my tx before are now not showing it, so unless it goes missing in everysite it does not mean its dropped right?

Comment: It's been dropped by those sites, but not by all

Comment: Does this mean there are chances it can be dropped by all soon?

Comment: That depends completely on the rules blockchain.info and others use for there mempools, there's no way to tell

Comment: @SharjeelAhmed Even if it is dropped by all sites that does not mean it will be dropped by all nodes, as MeshCollider has explained.